# UIAlertController above all views (iOS12)

Tags: uiactionsheet, ios12

I have added the button on top of all views:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!

window.addSubview(nextBtn)
```

And than I call UIAlertController

```
let ac = UIAlertController(title: "", message: NSLocalizedString("choose_type_physical_activity", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

....

present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And only on iOS 12 I have a button over my action sheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up39D.png)

Comment: And what’s the question?

Answer (score 0):

I just added my button to NavigationController not to UIWindow